# How to dump Permgen?

Tags: jvm, profiling, permgen

I wanted to take the dump of the Permgen of a application server.

I do not want to use `-XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading` as i do not want to restart the server, Neither i want to use `jconsole`.

I there any tool like `jmap`(used to heap dump didnt find any option for permgen) to get the permgen so that i can supply only the `pid`.

Comment: Did this help you solve your problem Vikas?

Comment: I have tried this earlier it was saying that invalid option and showing up the usage which says only -histo and -dump (heap dump) are allowed.I am using the jmap inside jdk/bin is this the right one

Comment: The `permstat` option is not available on MS Windows.

Answer (score 17):

```
jmap -permstat <pid>
```

is going to produce an output like that :

```
30337 intern Strings occupying 2746200 bytes.
class_loader    classes bytes   parent_loader   alive?  type

<bootstrap> 2031    7253392   null      live    <internal>
0x517474f0  1   1760      null      dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x43f95d38
0x4f83f670  1   1744    0x4ebfb8e8  dead    sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader@0x43f95d38
[...]

total = 287 10020   35889952        N/A     alive=3, dead=284       N/A
```

This is not a full dump, but doing that is going to allow you to do some investigation.

I am still looking on how to find more information.

Answer (score 13):

It is not possible to 'dump permgen' as it's done for the heap.

In addition to `jmap -permstat` as others have presented, you can analyze standard heap dump to shed some light on your permanent generation as described in [this blog entry: 'The Unknown Generation: Perm'](http://sites.google.com/site/eclipsebiz/The-Unknown-Generation-Perm).

> Because a heap dump does not really contain a lot of information about perm space, perm problems are difficult to tackle. Recently, I found this great article by Sporar, Sundararajan and Kieviet. The authors shed some light on the permanent generation. Of course, I had to check right away if and how I can use the Eclipse Memory Analyzer to analyze this “unknown” generation. This is what this blog is about.

Answer (score 1):

```
jmap -permstat <pid>
```